# Multi-threaded node creation in Neo4j

Tags: scala, transactions, neo4j

I created 1 million Neo4j nodes in batches of 10000, each batch in its own transaction. The strange thing is that parallelizing this process with multi-threaded execution did not have any positive effect on performance. It is as if the transactions in different threads are blocking each other.

Here's a piece of Scala code that tests this with the help of parallel collections:

```
import org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase

object Main extends App {

    val total = 1000000
    val batchSize = 10000

    val db = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase("neo4yay")

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
        new Thread(){override def run() = db.shutdown()}
    )

    (1 to total).grouped(batchSize).toSeq.par.foreach(batch => {

        println("thread %s, nodes from %d to %d"
            .format(Thread.currentThread().getId, batch.head, batch.last))

        val transaction = db.beginTx()
        try{
            batch.foreach(db.createNode().setProperty("Number", _))
        }finally{
            transaction.finish()
        }
    })
}
```

and here are the `build.sbt` lines needed for building and running it:

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "1.8.M07"

fork in run := true
```

One can switch between parallel and sequential modes by removing and adding `.par` invocation before the outer `foreach`. The console output clearly shows then that with `.par` execution is indeed multi-threaded.

To rule out possible problems with concurrency in this code, I have also tried an actor-based implementation, with about the same result (6 and 7 seconds for sequential and parallel versions, respectively).

So, the question is: did I do something wrong or this is a Neo4j limitation?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that your tx arrive at about the same time. And transaction commits are serialized writes to the transaction log. If the writes would be interleaved time-wise and the actual node-creation a more expensive process you would get a speedup.

Answer (score 2):

Batch insert does not work with multiple threads. From the neo4j Documentation:

> Always perform batch insertion in a single thread (or use synchronization to make only one thread at a time access the batch inserter) and invoke shutdown when finished.

[Neo4j Batch insert](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html)

Comment: The Batch inserter is not what Oleg used but the normal transactional API :)

Comment: I guess I read to many "batch"es in the text ;-) But writing with multiple threads into a file will be bottlenecked by the io speed (as you answered).